# Meteor displaying base64 image in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, base64

I am creating a Meteor app where the users could ask and anwser questions. I am using text editor for the user input. It allows the user to insert images and it inserts them in the database in base64 format. The question is is there a way to display them in the html with helpers. My code up to now:
posts:

```
function(){
        var posts = Posts.find({});
        var postsArray = [];
        posts.forEach(function(entry){
            var object = new Object();
            object.title = entry.title;
            object.image = entry.content.match(/src=(.*?)style/)[1];
            console.log(object);
            postsArray.push(object);
        })
        return postsArray;
     },// returns posts
```

HTML:

```
{{#each posts}}

        <h3>{{title}}</h3><br/>
        <img src={{image}}/>

    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the answer. The mistake was in the regular expression:

```
posts:function(){
        var posts = Posts.find({});
        var postsArray = [];
        posts.forEach(function(entry){
            var regex = /<img.*?src='(.*?)'/;
            var object = new Object();
            object.title = entry.title;
            object.image = entry.content.match(/<img src="(.*?)"/)[1];
            console.log(object);
            postsArray.push(object);
        })
        return postsArray;
     },// returns posts
```